# I'm having trouble with some fairly basic math functions in Xcode

Tags: objective-c

Basically, the program has 5 textfields for numbers. I want a math function that totals all 5 textboxes, then multiplies by 1.39, then again by 1.12, but I can't get the textfields to add properly. It works so far if you only put a number in one of the textfields, but it gets a little confused when it comes to adding more than one textfield. Here's my code:

```
- (IBAction)calculate {
    float b = ([BCB.text floatValue]);
    float d = b+([MCD.text floatValue]);
    float f = b+d+([SF.text floatValue]);
    float w = b+d+f+([SW.text floatValue]);
    float a = b+d+f+w+([AP.text floatValue]);
    float p = 1.39f;
    float h = 1.12f;
    float t = a*p*h;    

    Total.text = [ [NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f", t];
}
```

Bear in mind I'm 100% beginner when it comes to Xcode, and I've kind of Frankensteined this code together from various tutorials, and this might be completely wrong.

Comment: define 'confused'.   What are you getting for Total.text?

Comment: *sigh* Now I feel VERY stupid, immediately after posting this I went and figured out what I was doing wrong. When I used the floated 'a' variable, it was using "b+d+f+w+([AP.text floatValue]);" where each variable added the one before it, and so it was stacking variables.

Comment: How, in what single way, does this have to do or is this related to Xcode?!

Comment: in.... every single way? I'm coding this in Xcode...

Comment: Yeah but this can also be done in any other IDE or text editor. This is not related to Xcode at all.

Comment: My appologies, the fact I was coding it with Xcode made me think to tag it 'Xcode'. Surely you can see the logic.

Comment: By that logic, you could also have tagged it "keyboard". Xcode is just a development tool. It is not a programming language. Objective-C is one of many languages supported by Xcode, and Xcode is not the only development environment for Objective-C.

Comment: @user57368 @Radek: Chill out, folks. It's just a tag. Both of you have edit privileges; just change it and be done.

Comment: Sorry man, like I said in the question I'm 100% beginner at all this, I found this site through an Xcode tagged question referring to Objective-C programming for iPhone applications in Xcode, and figured I'd tag mine the same. I didn't mean to offend you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line:

```
float f = b+d+([SF.text floatValue]);
```

`d` already equals `b+([MCD.text floatValue])`, so `f` is assigned the value of `2*b + ([MCD.text floatValue])`, and more error builds up in the next two lines.  Just assign each floatValue to a variable by itself (i.e., `float f = [SF.text floatValue];` and so on) and then add them all together at the end.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the value of each text field only once, e.g.:

```
- (IBAction)calculate {
    float b = [BCB.text floatValue];
    float d = [MCD.text floatValue];
    float f = [SF.text floatValue];
    float w = [SW.text floatValue];
    float a = [AP.text floatValue];
    float p = 1.39f;
    float h = 1.12f;
    float t = (b+d+f+w+a)*p*h;    

    Total.text = [ [NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f", t];
}
```